# Colocar IF no WHERE para excluir linhas com base em mais de uma coluna

Tags: if, where

Olá, tenho a seguinte situação.
Preciso que a minha consulta não retorne as linhas quando a coluna Produto for '.COM' e a coluna cliente for 'DEDICADO'. Caso o Produto for qualquer outro, tem que retornar todos os clientes, inclusive o Dedicado.

Como que faço essa condição no WHERE?

Segue a tentativa falha:

```
SELECT S.PRODUTO, S.CLIENTE, S.EMISSAO
FROM SUPRIMENTOS S
WHERE S.EMISSAO BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-01'
AND S.PRODUTO NOT IN ('.COM') IF(S.CLIENTE = 'DEDICADO');
```

Comment: Poderia incluir a definição da tabela suprimentos.

Comment: AND ( (NOT (S.PRODUTO ='.COM' AND S.CLIENTE = 'DEDICADO')) OR (S.PRODUTO <> '.COM') )

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver assim: AND NOT (S.PRODUTO = '.COM' AND S.CLIENTE = 'DEDICADO')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
WHERE S.EMISSAO BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-01'
AND (S.PRODUTO <> '.COM' OR S.CLIENTE <> 'DEDICADO')
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver assim: AND NOT (S.PRODUTO = '.COM' AND S.CLIENTE = 'DEDICADO')

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso utilize [AND] ao invés de [OR], pq senão irá retornar produto = '.COM' e cliente = 'DEDICADO'.

```
WHERE S.EMISSAO BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-01'
AND (S.PRODUTO <> '.COM' OR S.CLIENTE <> 'DEDICADO')
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver assim: AND NOT (S.PRODUTO = '.COM' AND S.CLIENTE = 'DEDICADO')